# C# UWP how to create a save file

Tags: c#, save, win-universal-app

So i am new to this and i would need some guidance, I have an app(tichu counter)
in this app i have some controls and events happening which i handle.

Now here is the part.
Before navigating to the page of the app that does the tricks to count for people's scores i want to create another page. In that page i have 2 options one "New Game" and "Resume Game".
My problem is i don't know how to save my values and how to call them at the resume game.

I have 2 listviews to show my class Score.Each team gets a value to show, listA to ListView of team A, ListB to ListView of team B.

```
// So the listview knows something changed.
private ObservableCollection<Score> Scores;
//on page load
Scores = new ObservableCollection<Score>();

// this is how i add the scores inside the Score class
//teamAscore and teamBscore are the scores the user has typed inside
//the 2 textboxes i have(shown in picture below)
Scores.Add(new Score { ListA = teamAScore, ListB = teamBScore });

public class Score
{
    public int ListA { get; set; }
    public int ListB { get; set; }
}
```

With the lists i have 2 TextBlocks one for team A and one for team B. They are located above each listview and show the Overall score of its team as shown in this picture (http://prntscr.com/akavl6).

one thing is if i close the page and reopen it the Class and ofc the textblocks wont hold the values they already had. And pretty much i don't know how to go about this so that i save somewhere my lists and overall Scores so i can restore them when i go back to the page or delete them and start a new game with the values all to 0.

Comment: You can make it static. However if you want to save it and then load it when the user opens the app, It would be better to use this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saving values to Local storage is what you want. Now if its single values you can store it easily by assigning them to a string variable in local storage.
But would suggest you incorporate `SQlite database`. Since you are dealing with two ListViews so I am assuming the data keeps on increasing exponentially so it would be better to save those data in a database other than in some `.txt` file in local storage or creating new variables for each entry.
Though this is time consuming and a lot more code would be needed but with it you would save user data in a better format.
Though there are options of using `static data` or `parameter passing` while navigating but this would lead to loss of data once app session ends, app closes.

Comment: I see your Idea sounds good got any links that would help me get a better understanding of SQlite database? (sry for late response)

Comment: after studying some things on msdn forums(a small search because its getting late) i instaled the SQlite database extension. And when i saw the code it seems like he created the class as i did and added that class to the database. So that's the idea?

Comment: The idea is to save this database to Local Storage. Think of SQlite as just a container for easier access and well defined storage of data. Saving this data to local storage would ensure its availability even after you close the app. It will help you in the long run as most app developers use it to store their data.

Comment: oh i see so its like creating a txt file? but instead its an SQlite?

Comment: Yes but in text file you will need to store it as `JSON` format or some other format to access specific data like `highScore`, `currentScore`, `comboScore` etc. And mostly u end up reading whole file rewriting complete file which is not a feasible method in the long run with the increase in data.

Comment: ohh i see ok got any link to a simple tutorial? i found some but it gets complicated sometimes if you have it would be great. (sry for such a late responce i didnt have internet for these last days and couldnt check anything.

Comment: Dont forget to mark it as answer if I have answered your ques. As for tutorial remember Windows 8.1 app code is slightly different from Windows 10 Sqlite integration code. make sure you search the correct version.

Comment: okay i will search it today now that i am up and running again ofc i will mark it if it solves my problem i just need some time to do the SQlite thing ;p i am pretty sure this is what i want will check it today!